# I want my JFrame window to represent whole screen

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, layout-manager

Problem is when i create GUI in `jFrame` window on screen and run the program later it in full screen using

```
  setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

it do not show up like it looked in that window [see the red bordered area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z6OG.png)

[image]

Components appears in one corner of screen or only at a small part in center depending upon layouts and rest is empty space [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze2n6.png)

[image]

I want `JFrame` window (see the red bordered area in first image) which is showed while creating GUI **to represent my whole screen** so that i can know how it will look when i run it in full screen.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) From the screenshot, the problem seems to be about the use of layouts. But post a MCVE / SSCCE and we can give a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change the layout manager, may be using a combination of `BorderLayout` and `GridBagLayout`

These will provide you with a means to define how the components are positioned and sized within the parent container

See [Layout out components within a container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: changing layouts is what i am doing since this morning. nothing works. using a different layout just sends it to center or some other part of screen.

Comment: *"nothing works"* Advising you to post an MCVE / SSCCE doesn't seem to work either.. :(